# asp.net validation client side on client side or server side or both

Tags: javascript, asp.net

the official document says "Under most circumstances, you do not have to make any changes to your page or to the validation controls to use client-side validation. "
does it mean that validation controls will automatically generate javascript code  behind the scene to perform client side validation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, if you look into your `_validationScriptsPartial.cshtml` you will see which validation scripts will be loaded.
The tag helper use already existing validation libraries and insert the appropriate statements for the validation.

More informations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation).